# Selecting a link with Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

How can I select a link with selenium webdriver?

Selenium before would be done by:

```
    selenium.click("link=Users");
```

But how can I do the same with webdriver?

I thought about

```
    driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Users")).click();
```

but this does not work. No link is clicked!

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="mainpage" class="mainpage">
<div id="pageid" class="pageid">
<div id="body">

<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="id_menu" class="mymenu">
<ul>
<li class="li_class ">
<a href="/user.xhtml">Users</a>
```

stacktrace:

```
    org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: 
{"method":"partial link text","selector":"Users"} Command duration or timeout: 11.36 
seconds For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions
/no_such_element.html Build info: version: '2.24.1', revision: '17205', time: '2012-06-19 
17:28:14' System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', 
java.version: '1.7.0_02' Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver Session ID: 
178449d1-4ff3-44f3-b35c-6a158db7c430 error at line: 34
```

Comment: please provide the stack trace and html code snippet of the link (and its parent container). Normally the code you are using should work.

Comment: updated above wíth the entries stripped down to the menu element.

Comment: Does this link appear only after you hover over some element or click on some element?

Comment: which id should I use? I cannot modify the webpage, it is generated by jsf servlet. As I cannot change it, i have to find a way to anyway click the link with selenium?... @Sajan no the link does appear just on the screen without hovering.

Comment: instead of partialText, you should try, driver.findElement(By.linkText("H")).click(); since its the full text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

XPath is one of the most exact ways to *point* the element.

Try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.XPath("//li[@class='li_class']/a")).Click();
```

Comment: xpath empowers web driver even much more.

Comment: Under the hood, linkText and partialLinkText use XPath already.

Comment: XPath it's also the most painful, unreadable, unmantainable way. I'd recommend using just link text or otherwise the simplest/most semantical possible css selector.

Answer (score 8):

This should work:

```
driver.findElement(By.LinkText("Users")).click();
```

By LinkText is possible

Comment: The LinkText or PartialLinKText has never yet worked for me.  By id is great, and xpath works but for dynamically generated mark up and different browsers it can be tricky to keep xpath working all the time.

Answer (score 3):

Using a CSS selector:

```
a[href*=user.xhtml]
```

Here are some tips for writing cssSelector

```
 = --> Equals string
^= --> Starts with string
$= --> Ends with string
*= --> Contains 
~= --> Contains in a list
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Christoph - Link text should work.
But I follow a different approach which works for me all the time.

All the element that I need to locate or select I give them an id (without CSS there won't be any difference in view). This helps in readability of my test cases, writing functions for general stuff and improves maintainability of the code. Only for the dynamic generated code or places where I can't use id I go for different approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/user.xhtml']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the issue that LinkText and LinkPartialText didn´t work. This was because I uset then HTMLUnit Driver. Using FireFox both methods works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case chromedriver not allowed to click link, due to form obtain click. I was able to fix this by using:

```
if(driver.toString().contains("chrome")) {
        WebElement form=driver.findElement(By.id("form_id"));
            ((JavascriptExecutor)driver)
            .executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'display: block;')", form); //here I change visibility of element
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem using PHP Webdriver. LinkText or partialLinkText weren't working, but text provided for search was equal to this in SOURCE code. (lets say it was link text: "Users")

I was scratching my head why it is not working, when everywhere else it was. Then I saw the difference. In fact in source code link text was Users, but on display it was modified by css text-transform to lower case, so it was displayed as "users". When I changed my search criteria from Users to users it worked like harm!

So remember - webdriver actually works on data it see. Didn't have idea it is case sensitive at all! But it actually worked and solved my problem. Cheers!

Answer (score -2):

Try this out:

```
package mypack;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import mypackage.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class classnew {

    private static FirefoxDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //String baseUrl = "http://newtours.demoaut.com/";
      FirefoxDriver Firefoxdriver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver = null;
        driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com");

        String linkText1 = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("egis")).getText();
        System.out.println(linkText1);
        String linkText2 = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("EGIS")).getText();
        System.out.println(linkText1);  
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: am getting error as Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at mypack.classnew.main(classnew.java:17)
please tell me where am doing wrong