# How to verify link using selenium web driver

Tags: selenium

How to verify a link in selenium-java web driver.
I need to verify "linkname" is a link and pass the test case.
How can I verify that.

Comment: What language are you using? Did you try anything and it didn't work?

Comment: I am using Java..I am just searching that I need to verify that as a link and click it pass the test case else i need to fail it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12091232/1119381

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: if(driver.findElement(By.linkText("YourLinkName")).isDisplayed()
{ 
// pass the test
} else {
//fail the test
 }

Comment: after that how can I use assert?

Comment: Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.linkText("YourLinkName")).isDisplay‌​ed())

Answer (score 1):

Selenium webdriver provides a feature to identify the links in the web pages in two ways. Linktext and Partial Link text.
You can use the below code to identify the links in the web page.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.findElement(By.linkText("Click Here")).click();// Linktext

driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Click ")).click(); //Partial Link text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this, First locate the element and then use `isDisplayed()` to check whether it is there are not:

```
Webelement linkName= driver.findElement(By.linkText("Name of Link "));

if(linkName.isDisplayed())
{
  System.out.println("Yes link is there")
}
else
{
  System.out.println("No link is there")
}
```

Also you can use any locator to locate the Element or Link it is not necessary to use the `LinkText` only. You can use `id`, `name` , `xpath` or `class` name also.